# Applying RewriteRules

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I was wondering if the following is possible:

Say I have a site root at

```
domain.com/test/Project/web/app.php
```

Is it possible to set everything up that that location is accessible through

```
test.domain.com/Project
```

I've tried some small snippets but there was no effect. (I placed the .htaccess at the project's root, so in the Project folder, before the web folder).

Anyone that could point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you provide the snippets that you did try?

Comment: If you've already configured a sub-domain it's probably better to do the rewrite in the relevant `<VirtualHost>` directive in *httpd-vhosts.conf* rather than an *.htaccess*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty simple:
.htaccess (placed in the root of your subdomains htdocs)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test.domain.com
RewriteRule ^Project/$ http://domain.com/test/Project/web/app.php [L]
```

Make sure, that rewriting is enabled :)

Comment: Do you need further help on this?

Comment: Hey guys sorry for the late response, busy times. Thanks for the help, this solved it!